# broken image with ng-src tag false in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a wordpress, I have auto rent theme installed but when I add the product in my wordpress website using woocommerce it's showing broken images, for product, I have deactivated the plugins one by one but still the same thing happening. Here is [my site link](https://www.seodemoweb.com/click-motor.com/cars/)

Comment: There is no 'src' attribute for your images... you need to check what is causing that.

Comment: Any suggestion how can i check that?